# Using ampscript to get all records in a data extension between 2 dates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Using `Marketing Cloud`:

I have a data extension with a date field. On a cloudpage, using ampscript, i need to get all the records from that data extension where the date field is between/including 2 dates.

The `LookupRows` function seems to be the best available but i can only directly compare values to each other, it can't use a `"between"` statement.

What would be the best way to achieve this ? ( Other than executing a `LookupRows` for each date separately )

Comment: You want to use it in messages or in CloudPages/Microsites?

Comment: CloudPage/Microsite

Comment: How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: Should be between 0 and 100 or so

Answer (score 2):

You will likely need to utilize SSJS via the [Rows.Retrieve function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.htm).

Sample script:

```
var yourDE = DataExtension.Init("yourDE");
var complexfilter = {
                LeftOperand:{
                    Property:"Date",
                    SimpleOperator:"greaterThan",
                    Value: {{Start Date}}
                },
                LogicalOperator:"AND",
                RightOperand:{
                    Property:"Date",
                    SimpleOperator:"lessThan",
                    Value: {{End Date}}
        }};
var filterdata = yourDE.Rows.Retrieve(complexfilter);
```

Be aware though, this will only allow a maximum return of 2500 rows for each retrieve.

To get around this, you will need to do 1 of two things.

1. Utilize [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm) to do this Retrieve Request and then use ContinueRequest property.

Sample Continue Request in SSJS:

```
do { 

    //your Retrieve Request API here

    rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;

} while (runstatus == "MoreDataAvailable")
```

2. Create a Query in SFMC and run it prior to each pull and then utilize the resulting DE as a reference for your AMPscript - I would include an attribute named 'Secret' with a value of 1 - for easy reference in your lookup.

Sample SQL:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, 1 as Secret
FROM yourDE
WHERE Date >= '2017/02/25' and Date <= '2017/12/07'
```